# What visa does my fiancée need to come to the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, malaysian-citizens

I'm in need of information on what is the correct visa for my fiancée.

I'm a British citizen and my partner is Malaysian. She is looking to join me in the UK next year. We intend to get married.

What type of visa should she apply for? She needs to work in the UK as she has to support family in Malaysia.

Comment: Do you [earn enough to sponsor your partner to settle](https://www.gov.uk/join-family-in-uk/eligibility)? Did you read through the [gov.uk on "Apply to join family living permanently in the UK"](https://www.gov.uk/join-family-in-uk)?

Comment: Have you ever lived in another EU/EEA country?

Answer (score 1):

She needs a ‘family of a settled person’ visa. It's not cheap though £1,195. 
See more at https://www.gov.uk/join-family-in-uk/overview

Comment: ...unless she can use the Surinder Singh route (not that there's any indication that it applies in this case, but it deserves mention in case it does: there's a significant difference between £1195 and £0!).